# Why do my flames look horizontally stretched when rendered?

Tags: video, tracking, compositing-nodes

I have a scene where I want a car to look like it is on fire as I drive by it.

When changing to RenderMode, my motion track looks good (enough). It is in the right location and does not move relative to the car (masking to come later).

[image]

However, once I have rendered the image and composited it, the flame is distorted (horizontally stretched?) and in the wrong location.

[image]

I tried scaling the images to render size:

[image]

I also tried without the scale nodes, and with every permutation of the scale nodes. I have also tried rebaking the smoke, to no effect.

Comment: My guess is that your footage either has another aspect ratio or different dimensions. Check your *Movie Clip properties and settings* or better use an image sequence of the clip with a 1:1 pixel ratio and try to match the output dimensions in the first place.

Comment: The footage has the same dimensions as an input. Like I said, whether or not I scale to render, the composited image looks the same. I'm also rendering out with an aspect ratio of 1x1

Comment: Also, I rendered out a cube next to the flames, and the cube is not distorted.

Comment: UPDATE: I don't know what was wrong, but I deleted the smoke domain and recreated it, works now.

Comment: Sounds like you scaled your domain by accident...?